# How do you skip few index in a for...of loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

with the good old for loop I can do things like:

```
for (let i=0; i<bla.length; i+=2){
...
}
```

So for every count, I can skip the index by doing a +2.

I know `for...of` is the future but I can't quite figure how to skip the index?

```
for (const [i, element] of bla.entries()) {
...
}
```

Comment: `I know for...of is the future` Does not mean you have to give up what you already have; You can still do what you want using filter or indexing but  at this point it will be like "Swatting flies with a sledgehammer" you can do it but why

Comment: True, not given up things in the past. Maybe I should rephrase better. I'm learning how to convert from the `old for` loop to the new `for ... of` loop.

Comment: Also it is a good practice to use for of loop when you need to iterate over all the elements; Keep things simple easy to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer of this depends on whether you would like to preserve the original index, if so, you may add an `if` statement within the for loop

```
for (const [i, element] of bla.entries()) {
   if (!(i % 2)) {
       // do something here
   }
}
```

if you don't care about preserving the original index then you may just add a filter before or after `entries`:

```
for (const [i, element] of bla.entries().filter((e, i) => !(i % 2))) {
   // do something
}
```